# nginx wont let me allow only server ip

Tags: nginx

i can access `example.com` and `example.com/apiroute/`

but i want `example.com/apiroute/` to only be accessible from my webapp container.

i believe what is happening is:

someone visits `example.com/apiroute/` ---> it goes into the nginx container that is running on a bridge network with the subnet of `10.88.2.0/24` ---> then it gets directed to the `location = /apiroute/` ---> then it gets allowed in.

the issue is my webapp container runs on the same bridge network, so it has the same ip. if i block this subnet, the webapp container cant access the api url.  and i need them to be on the same network.

so, i'm trying to figure out a way to configure this...

**default.conf:**

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080;
  server_name 12.34.56.78 www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080 default;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 4430 ssl;
    listen [::]:4430 ssl default ipv6only=on;
    server_name  https://example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/_cert/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/_cert/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/_cert/etc/letsencrypt/live/dhparam.pem;

    ########################################################################
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
    ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # Requires nginx => 1.3.7
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    # Disable strict transport security for now. You can uncomment the following
    # line if you understand the implications.
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    ########################################################################


root /etc/nginx/html;
location / {
    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/cors.txt;
}


location ~* {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://abda_1;

        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on; 
}


location = /apiroute/ {
    
    allow 12.34.56.78;
    # allow 10.88.2.0/24;
    deny all;
    proxy_pass http://api_route/apiroute/;
        
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;

}



    #error_page 404 /404.html;
    #location = /404.html {
    #}

    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #}

}
```

Comment: do you have another nginx on top of this one that proxies all requests here?

Comment: @Grin i dont.  and i tried adding ```proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;``` but it doesn't seem to do anything.